# How to execute Javascript function in C++

Tags: javascript, c++, linux, ubuntu

**Please tell me, how to include a javascript header file or javascript function in C++ code. The C++ code is written in Linux(UBUNTU)?**

Although i need to perform the above action only, but let me tell u my purpose of doing it, as i am intending to implement CTI (Computer Telephony Integration) operation.

(Help will be appreciated)  Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: javascript depend on the browser..  doesn't it?

Comment: @sunglim, JavaScript is a general-purpose programming language that happens to be prevalent in browsers. There is no dependency, as such.

Comment: @sunglim: Javascript is a dialect of ECMAscript. You will find many flavors of ECMAscript like Javascript (interpreted by different engines for browsers), Jscript.NET, Actionscript, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Calling Scripting functions from C++

http://clipp.sourceforge.net/Tutorial/back_calling.html

JavaScript Calls from C++ - CodeGuru

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/ieprogram/article.php/c4399/JavaScript-Calls-from-C.htm

JavaScript call from C++ - CodeProject

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/jscalls.aspx

calling javascript from c++ code - JavaScript / Ajax / DHTML answers

http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/759793-calling-javascript-c-code

Try All of above this.

Answer (score 6):

You *might* want to port your JS to C++; this should be a fairly simple task, as the two languages are moderately alike.

Simply porting the functionality is likely to be *far* simpler than actually trying to use a JS parsing library, and likely less error prone.

Comment: That's a good suggestion... also C# 4.0 is scarily close to JavaScript - just make all functions return a 'dynamic' and you're almost there.. see http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL16/

Comment: It is probably feasible to automatically port JavaScript to C++, since there are already several [JavaScript compilers that target C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31307856/975097).

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript is not a compiled language and it is not, by any stretch of the imagination, compatible with C++, so `#include` doesn't stand a chance of importing JavaScript code. In fact, the notion of a header file doesn't even exist in JavaScript.

There are several JavaScript engines that can be integrated into a compiled language, including:

1. The Mozilla project's [SpiderMonkey](http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/).
2. Google Chrome's [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/).
3. A whole bunch of [others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ECMAScript_engines).

Answer (score 2):

A detailed tutorial for embedding JS in C++ via Mozilla's SpiderMonkey engine can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/How_to_embed_the_JavaScript_engine) Basically you need to include jsapi.h, create/configure/cleanup the JS engine as the tutorial describes (populating the char* script with your string literal JS source code and passing the resulting character array to JS_EvaluateScript), and then link against the SpiderMonkey library when you build the executable for your system.  Note that this tutorial goes on to explain how to call C functions from JS and how to call specific JS functions from C, which is also interesting and possibly more appropriate for the OP's situation.