# JavaScript function call from C++ Program

Tags: javascript, c++, graphics, glut, embedding

I have seen a few questions pertaining to embedding JS in a c++ program or calling js functions from c++.  I was wondering if it was possible to call javascript functions that have graphics from a c++ program, specifically a GLUT program.  I have heard of V8 and other JS engines but I wasn't sure if they were able to display graphics on the screen of a c++ window(like a glut, glu, or sdl window).

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713289/how-to-execute-javascript-function-in-c

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  My question is specifically based around javascript graphics displayed on a c++ window.

Comment: I'm not sure what you aim at, or what is you list of requirements (what is allowed or not for you), since there are plenty of possibility here. - having a navigator subwindow in you c++ application - having js doing everything but graphics - having a js doing graphics on a not-web way (nodejs+package) - ...

Here, somehow, you seem to want to have some part of graphics done in C++, and some part of graphics done in JS ? which doing what, split how ? (and expecting sharing a graphics context ?)