# How to call javascript functions from native c++ without touching the browser in Windows without using any library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, c++, visual-c++

I have some html files and there are java script functions in html files.

I have to call java script functions from Native C++ without touching the browser.

I don't have to use any frameworks and I can't use internet explorer under the my code because internet explorer doesn't support all java script functions.

So please give me a reasonable advise.

Comment: So you mean you want a library that can execute javascript code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute Javascript function in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713289/how-to-execute-javascript-function-in-c)

Comment: I can not use any library because the exe should be very thin not more then 300 kb.

Comment: @ggdev: Are you asking how to write your own engine to interpret and execute JavaScript?

Comment: Size is not a reason for not using a library. It's a reason for not using a big library. You should add this to your question. But with these limitations, you'll just have to implement your own JavaScript engine, which is probably not feasible.

Comment: Implementing javascript parsing would be way too broad for a single question. The only other solution is to have something execute the code for you so it will be a library or another program. And you cannot parse all javascript with only a 300KB program. If you can you are definitely an expert coder.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the answers. I will try to find a small library.